# how to get back jquery after ajax load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i made an ajax request in a div container in my index.php, and in one of my page load by ajax i have this jquery function:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 var section = document.querySelector('.vs-section');
 var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.vs-transform');
   
 var smooth = new Smooth({
    direction: 'horizontal',
    section: section,
    ease: 0.1,
    els: divs
   });
   smooth.init();
});
```

and this function does not work if i make my ajax request.
But if i insert my

```js
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

inside this page it's working but the problem is i load jquery already in my index.php so it load it 2 times so how i can i get my jquery working without reload it as a tween?

this is my ajax:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    $("#menu a").click(function(){ 
       page=$(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            url: "pages/"+page,
            cache:false,
            success:function(html){
                afficher(html);
    history.pushState({key : 'value'}, 'hash', page);
            }, 
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown){
                afficher("erreur lors du chagement de la page");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
 
     $('#container').on('click', '.vs-transform a', function(){
  var page=$(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            url: "pages/"+page,
            cache:false,
            success:function(html){
                afficher(html);
    history.pushState({key : 'value'}, 'hash', page);
            },
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown){
                afficher ("erreur lors du chagement de la page");
            }
        });
        return false;
 }); 
window.onpopstate = function(event){
  if(event.state === null){
      // alert('bien');
  }
 };
});

  
function afficher(data){
$("#container").delay( 100 ).fadeOut(400,function(){
    $("#container").empty();    
    $("#container").append(data);
    $("#container").fadeIn(500); 
});
}
```

Comment: load jquery once in your main header from the cdn and this won't be an issue.

Comment: you should provide a callback for the ajax success and execute the code for the ajax loaded page inside the callback. Your code cannot work if you don't execute it after attaching the html of the ajax call in the DOM

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){` isn't needed if it's being executed as the result of an asynchronous ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that the `afficher()` function attaches the loaded code to the DOM you can try something like this:

```
 $('#container').on('click', '.vs-transform a', function(){
     var page=$(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            url: "pages/"+page,
            cache:false,
            success:function(html){
                afficher(html);
                history.pushState({key : 'value'}, 'hash', page);
                //HERE THE INNER PAGES CODE
                if(page==="yorpagehere.html"){    
                   //here code for yourpagehere.html
                   var section = document.querySelector('.vs-section');
                   var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.vs-transform');

                   var smooth = new Smooth({
                       direction: 'horizontal',
                       section: section,
                       ease: 0.1,
                       els: divs
                   });
                   smooth.init();

                }
            },
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown){
                afficher ("erreur lors du chagement de la page");
            }
        });
        return false;
    // ....
```

EDIT. This should work with the delay

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#menu a").click(function(){ 
       page=$(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            url: "pages/"+page,
            cache:false,
            success:function(html){
                afficher(html, page);
                history.pushState({key : 'value'}, 'hash', page);
            }, 
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown){
                afficher("erreur lors du chagement de la page");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

     $('#container').on('click', '.vs-transform a', function(){
     var page=$(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            url: "pages/"+page,
            cache:false,
            success:function(html){
                afficher(html, page);
                history.pushState({key : 'value'}, 'hash', page);
            },
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown){
                afficher ("erreur lors du chagement de la page");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }); 
window.onpopstate = function(event){
        if(event.state === null){
               // alert('bien');
        }
    };
});


function afficher(data, page){
$("#container").delay( 100 ).fadeOut(400,function(){
    $("#container").empty();                
    $("#container").append(data);
    $("#container").fadeIn(500);
    if(page==="yorpagehere.html"){    
        //here code for yourpagehere.html
        var section = document.querySelector('.vs-section');
        var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.vs-transform');

        var smooth = new Smooth({
           direction: 'horizontal',
           section: section,
           ease: 0.1,
           els: divs
         });
         smooth.init();

      }
});
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see that you have to do the same in the success function of the $("#menu a").click() ajax. Be sure to edit the yorpagehere.html with the name of the page you want to execute the code for

Comment: yes reset my page name and make it for my success function of the menu link but still dont work i did not understand what i have to execute in my function afficher

Comment: mmm... ok sorry my fault again, i didn't see that you dealy the append... wait a minute and i edit mi answer